# IE 11 submit button click event not working under form tag?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have one submit button `.ButtonDownload` inside `form` tag. Invoking this function is not causing any form submission. But it works in another browser like Chrome, Firefox.

```
function downloadrefinementlogs() {
  $('form:first').data('postdata', 1);
  $('.ButtonDownload').click(); }
```

I have tried solutions like inserting a dummy button before this button, `return false`/stopping event propagation. The button also has a `name` property but nothing works.
Surprisingly, if I create a exact replica of this button with changed name & id that also didn't work.

Edit 1 :
Some HTML captured from the DEV tool around the button

```
<input name="ZS_SG_Theme_wt1$block$wtMainContent$wt18$SilkUIFramework_wt2$block$wtContent$wt8$wt139" tabindex="26" class="Button ButtonDownload Hidden ThemeGrid_MarginGutter" id="ZS_SG_Theme_wt1_block_wtMainContent_wt18_SilkUIFramework_wt2_block_wtContent_wt8_wt139" type="submit" value="ButtonDownload">
```

The Hidden element, whom after removing fixes the issue somehow.

```
<input name="ZS_SG_Theme_wt1$block$wtMainContent$wt18$SilkUIFramework_wt2$block$wtContent$wt8$wtMultiGeoStateFieldInput" tabindex="70" class="Hidden MultiGeoStateField ThemeGrid_Width1 ThemeGrid_MarginGutter" id="ZS_SG_Theme_wt1_block_wtMainContent_wt18_SilkUIFramework_wt2_block_wtContent_wt8_wtMultiGeoStateFieldInput" aria-invalid="false" onkeydown="return OsEnterKey('ZS_SG_Theme_wt1_block_wtMainContent_wt18_SilkUIFramework_wt2_block_wtContent_wt8_wt334', arguments[0] || window.event);" type="text" maxlength="50">
```

Comment: Do you have more than one element with `class="ButtonDownload"`? - and why not just `$('form:first').submit()` or `$('form:first')[0].submit()` ?

Comment: @mplungjan I only have 1 form

Comment: Console errors? Please show the html in a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan No errors but while debugging at runtime I tried deleting each element and hitting button until I found 1 specific hidden field whom I deleted and the button click worked. I don't know why this is happening as there is no direct relation with the button. I also cannot simple delete that field

Comment: Is the HTML possibly invalid then? Test it at w3org

Comment: HTML is automatically produced by the tool(Outsystems).

Comment: Can you show the generated HTML around the button, especially the element you removed?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the code you provide. How do you call the `downloadrefinementlogs` function? Can you please provide a code snippet which can **reproduce** the issue? Besides, when you click the submit button, the value of the hidden element will also be submitted. You can check the value of the hidden element to see if it is incompatible with IE.

Comment: @YuZhou the hidden field stores serialized JSON, removing this field works fine but something is with this field that aborts the form submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the above comment from @Yu Zhou,

After observing the field I found that max-length attribute was causing the issue. The max length was set to 50 chars and the JSON that got stored was more than that, which caused the `form` submission to invalidate and block the download. But still I am unsure of how the it worked in Chrome even though the hidden field value had more characters than the max length.

Answer (score -1):

check if your submit button has the attribute `name`, if not, try to add it to your submit button.

```
<input name="MyButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
```